# How to add a page to the Yoast breadcrumbs

Tags: plugin-wp-seo-yoast, breadcrumb

I am using Yoasts Wordpress SEO and I have set up my breadcrumbs. The problem is that my page setup is s follows.

```
/
/about
/blog - On this page I query the posts and display them. The posts themselves have nothing before them in the URL.
```

The breadcrumb shows as follows.

```
Home / Category / Page Title
```

I want it to show like this.

```
Home/ Blog / Category / Page Title
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 34):

Here's the general principle of what you need to do:

1. Hook into the `wpseo_breadcrumb_links` or `wp_seo_get_bc_ancestors` [API filters](http://yoast.com/wordpress/seo/api/).
2. Add your **Blog** into the WordPress SEO Breadcrumb `$links` array, using [`array_splice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php).

Place this in your theme's `functions.php`:

```
/**
 * Conditionally Override Yoast SEO Breadcrumb Trail
 * http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/wordpress-seo/trunk/frontend/class-breadcrumbs.php
 * -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

add_filter( 'wpseo_breadcrumb_links', 'wpse_100012_override_yoast_breadcrumb_trail' );

function wpse_100012_override_yoast_breadcrumb_trail( $links ) {
    global $post;

    if ( is_home() || is_singular( 'post' ) || is_archive() ) {
        $breadcrumb[] = array(
            'url' => get_permalink( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) ),
            'text' => 'Blog',
        );

        array_splice( $links, 1, -2, $breadcrumb );
    }

    return $links;
}
```

Note: You may need to update the code specific to your site or needs, but the general idea stays the same.

Comment: This worked perfectly, after changing my conditionals, url and text values to suit my needs. Thanks.

Comment: Weird. This code replaced 'Category' with 'Blog' instead of adding it before.

Comment: FIXED: in my case it needed "2, -3" instead of "1, -2" not sure why but it works that way.

Comment: @rjb thanks, very helpful code! Do you know how to add a page to the trail instead of removing one?